How to type a mock in python?

@patch("main.requests")
def test_get_joke(mock_get_joke):
    mock_response = MagicMock()
    mock_response.status_code = 200
    mock_response.json.return_value = {"value": "joke"}
    mock_get_joke.get.return_value = mock_response
    assert get_joke() == "joke"



my ide(vscode) can't make autocomplete for status_code, json, get
how to do typing correctly that ide autocomplite methods from request(json, get ...) and from mock(return_value) ?
I trying way with cast and with spec but in doesn't work correctly

If you are mocking the package requests have you looked at responses A utility library for mocking out the requests Python library. https://github.com/getsentry/responses

You can use unittest.mock.create_autospec to create a mock object that mimics the actual requests library's attributes and methods. So the IDE will understand the available methods like status_code, json, and get
from unittest.mock import patch, MagicMock, create_autospec
from typing import cast
import requests

@patch("main.requests")
def test_get_joke(mock_requests: MagicMock):
    mock_response = create_autospec(requests.Response, instance=True)
    mock_response.status_code = 200
    mock_response.json.return_value = {"value": "joke"}

    mock_requests.get.return_value = mock_response

    assert len_joke() > 0


it doesn't work, create_autospec take an object, requests - it is package
